# Mouse Hover - Hide Border?

Tags: html, css

How to hide border on the right when you hover on any item? Currently, all the items are set to `border-left: 1px solid #ccc;`

See example: http://jsfiddle.net/ktsyf8wf/

HTML

```
<div style="background-color: #ffffff; padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc">
    <ul class="monitoring-tabs">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li class="active">Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.monitoring-tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 25px;
}

.monitoring-tabs li {
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 0 17px;
    color: #4e5665;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.monitoring-tabs li:first-child {
    border-left:  1px solid #ffffff;
}

.monitoring-tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #e9eaed;
    border-left:  1px solid #ffffff;
}
.monitoring-tabs .active {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *I believe* it's a bad practice you can do the following:

Using the `+` operator you can change the properties of a sibling element.

```
.monitoring-tabs li:hover + li {
    border-left: {change here};
}
```

Basically, removing a border would be:

```
border-left: 0;
```

But than you'll have a missing pixel and you'll notice a "glitch", so the alternative is to change only the color of the border;

```
.monitoring-tabs li:hover + li {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ktsyf8wf/5/

Comment: You said "While it's a bad practice" so what is a good practice to do?

Comment: I believe that you should use `border-right` for the element itself, so the `hover` effect won't need to involve the sibling.

Answer (score 3):

Just add this to your CSS

```
.monitoring-tabs li:hover + li {
    border-left:  1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/953zgrhm/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use jquery to solve this problem and this code :

```
$(".monitoring-tabs li").hover(function(){
$(".monitoring-tabs li").next().css({"border": "0" });
});
```

it worked for deleting borders but after mouse over borders will not back to first , i have same prblem in my questions

Comment: It's rarely appropriate to suggest jQuery to a JavaScript question that doesn't specifically want a jQuery solution, but it's doubly inappropriate when the question isn't about JavaScript at all.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your css with following

```
<style type="text/css">
    .monitoring-tabs {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        clear: both;
        overflow: hidden;
        line-height: 25px;
    }

        .monitoring-tabs li {
            float: left;
            font-size: 13px;
            border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 0 17px;
            color: #4e5665;
            line-height: 30px;
        }

            /*.monitoring-tabs li:first-child {
                border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
            }*/

            .monitoring-tabs li:hover {
                background-color: #e9eaed;
                border-right: none;
            }

        .monitoring-tabs .active {
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
        }
</style>
```